# Python web scraping - Why do I get this error?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get text from a website using bs4 but I keep getting this error and I don't know why. This is the error: **TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method**.

This is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import bs4

url = "https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/dallas-pittsburgh-odds-august-5-2021-1410371"
page = urlopen(url)

html_bytes = page.read()
html = html_bytes.decode("utf-8")

text = html.find("div", {"class":"gc-score__title"})#the error is in this line
print(text)
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback that you get

Comment: this is all the traceback i get

Comment: No, that is not the full traceback. That is just the last line of it.

Comment: Also, you never use `bs4.BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
text = html.find("div", {"class":"gc-score__title"})
```

you just use [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) method, not `bs4.BeautifulSoup.find` method

So if you do

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find("div", {"class":"gc-score__title"})
print(text)
```

you will get rid of the error.
That said, the site is using JavaScript, so this will not yield what you expect. You will need to use tools like Selenium to scrape this site.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want BeautifulSoup to parse the data, you need to ask it to do that.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/dallas-pittsburgh-odds-august-5-2021-1410371"
page = urlopen(url)
html_bytes = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_bytes)
```

Then you can used `soup.find` to find `<div>` tags:

```
text = soup.find("div", {"class":"gc-score__title"})
```

That will eliminate the error. You were calling `str.find` because `html` is a string, and to pick tags out you need to call the `find` method of a `bs4.BeautifulSoup` object.

But besides eliminating the error, that line won't do what you want. It won't return anything, because the data at that url does not contain the tag `<div class="gc-score__title">`.

Copy the contents of `html_bytes` to a text editor to confirm this.